# Compiler pass registering in a symfony 2 controller

Tags: symfony

I wrote a compiler pass (a class implementing `CompilerPassInterface`) and I would like to register it with the DI container from one of my controllers. What I am trying to do is making a certain service X collect other services (Y, Z, ...) that are tagged in a certain manner. Outside a controller I would simply do:

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$container->addCompilerPass(new TransportCompilerPass);
```

But in my case I want to use the container made available to the controller so that I can leverage the definitions in services.xml I added to my application. I find it weird that the $this->container of the controller has the `get` method but not the `addCompilerPass`. Clearly it must be because `$this->container` is not a `ContainerBuilder`.

Anyhow ... can anyone show me a way around it?

Answer (score 2):

ooooops

when u wanna register a compiler pass this must be done in the bundle class and not in any of the controllers of the budle. This link explains everything:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html